# Why do syslog and gdb show different load address for the same shared library?

Tags: c, linux, gdb, shared-libraries

I'm facing a segmentation fault. Syslog reports the following:

```
segfault at 0 ip 00000000f71ff256 sp 00000000f44fee50 error 4 in libprotobuf-c.so.0.0.0[f71f8000+f000]
```

So, libprotobuf-c.so is loaded at `0xf71f8000`. When I loaded the respective core file in gdb and tried `info sharedlibrary`, it shows `FROM` address as `0xf71f9f70` which is different from what syslog showed. I'm not able to understand this mismatch. Could someone please help?

```
0xf71f9f70  0xf7204028  Yes (*)     /usr/lib/libprotobuf-c.so.0
```

Comment: I have reopened, as your question isn't about DLLs, but .so libs

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thanks for reopening. Does your earlier comment  about the behaviour still holds good? Why is that address mismatch?

Comment: I can talk about Windows and the damn DLLs, but probably different on Linux. that said, notice that there are 2 addresses: the theorical address and the actual load address, so maybe the problem is the same for linux. I cannot help more, except by voting on your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, libprotobuf-c.so is loaded at `0xf71f8000`. When I loaded the respective core file in gdb and tried info sharedlibrary, it shows FROM address as `0xf71f9f70` which is different from what syslog showed.

Actually they *are* the same. GDB shows start of `.text` as the `From` address.

If you do `readelf -WS /usr/lib/libprotobuf-c.so.0 | grep '\.text'`, you'll discover that `.text` starts at `0xf71f9f70 - 0xf71f8000 == 0x1f70`.